# Unexpected behavior Using React useState, Very strange output

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I am a newbie in React. I was experimenting around to see how things work,
and I found a very strange Behavior of React or useState whatever you want to call it.

Please, Someone, explain, what is going on and how this piece of coding is working.

```js
const {useState} = React;


let referceGiver = 0;
function giveNewRef() {
  let a = referceGiver;
  console.log("Making New Reference | Ref = ", a);
  referceGiver++;
  return a;
}

function App() {
  let v = "10";
  console.log("%cIniside Function", "background-color:red", `| v = ${v}`);

  let [val, setVal] = useState('30');

  const currentReference = giveNewRef();
  console.log("Outer Function Reference = ", currentReference)

  console.log("Value of UseState Val = ", val);

  function clicked() {
    v += ' 20';
    console.log("Inner Function Reference = ", currentReference);
    console.log("Value of V = ", v);
    setVal(v);
  }
  console.log("%cGoing To Return", "background-color:green");
  console.log('-----------------------------')

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{val + " " + Math.random()}</h1>
      <button onClick={clicked} > Click </button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector('#mount'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="mount"/>
```

[Output of the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITTGB.jpg)

Tell me why:

- inner and outer reference is different
- useState does not change 2 times but changes a third time
- giveNewRef() increasing value by 2

Comment: u need to import 'React' too along with 'useState'....

Comment: @skmak I dont think there is an issue when you import them separate

Comment: Not able to reproduce, made your code in a working snippet,  and giveNewRef increases by 1 each time.

Comment: @Keith what did you do, to make it increase by 1

Comment: I did nothing, I just made your code you posted into a working snippet..  Click Run code Snippet above to see the results..